# sun.java2d.opengl=true doesn't work with Windows Netbeans Platform Applications

Tags: java, netbeans, jogl, platform

For Netbeans platform applications using Jogl, I cannot run my project if I set sun.java2d.opengl=true on Windows (both 64 and 32, XP, Vista, and 7). Unfortunately, setting this to false creates other problems.

The GUI just will not start if I set this to true and I am using the GLCanvas or GLJPanel. The program just hangs in loading forever.

Do you have any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: What's exactly the problem when you try to run your project? Some error message? Does it crash?

Comment: The GUI just will not start if I set this to true and I am using the GLCanvas or GLJPanel. The program just hangs in loading forever.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set openGL flag to true it's unnecessary.If you use Graphics2D the graphics build int java just then you need to turn on the openGL flag.

Comment: If I set it to false, the program is not usable. On Mac this works fine. Only on Windows and Linux does everything blow up. Unfortunately, I can't use NEWT on Mac at the moment, since it doesn't work at all.